# Multiple authors and affiliations in LyX

Tags: lyx, author, affiliation

I want to add multiple authors and affiliations for each, without repeating footnotes when the affiliation is the same. Consider this:

[image]

which produces this:

[image]

and in the bottom of the page:

[image]

There are 2 problems here:

1. For Juan Carlos the two footnote symbols are overlapping.
2. It would be nice to give Juan Carlos and Raúl the same affiliation footnote symbol instead of repeating.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To solve your first problem, add space between the two consecutive  footnotes.
2. For you second problem, you can use `\footnotemark[2]`, this will only print the symbol of the second footnote, without adding one.

#### content of the LyX file:

[image]

#### the output:

Title:

[image]

Footnotes:

[image]

#### LyX File:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Title Of Article
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Juan Carlos
\begin_inset Foot
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Corresponding author, j.carlos@gmail.com
\end_layout

\end_inset

 
\begin_inset Foot
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
University A
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
and
\end_layout

\end_inset

 Ra
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
'
\end_layout

\end_inset

ul Gomez
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
footnotemark[2]
\backslash
and
\end_layout

\end_inset

 Marc Frankhauser
\begin_inset Foot
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
University B
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```